Laravel Mail Attachment: Error while sending attachment
I have communication service to handle/send all the communication throughout the application. When I try to send an e-mail with attachment of size more than 100KB gives me below SQS exception. I am not able to understand why I am getting the exception.
I have changed php.ini for both cli/apache
post_max_size = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
Exception Details;

Mail-Exception:  ["[object] (Aws\Sqs\Exception\SqsException(code:
0): Error executing "SendMessage" on
"https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/**/dev-"; AWS HTTP
error: Client error: POST https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/******/dev-**** resulted in a
400 Bad Request response:\n<ErrorResponse
xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">SenderI
(truncated...)\n InvalidParameterValue (client): One or more
parameters are invalid. Reason: Message must be shorter than 262144
bytes.


Presumably this is a restriction about the email message specifically, rather than the PHP file upload limit

"Reason: Message must be shorter than 262144 bytes." - with the attachment embedded, yours appears to be hitting that limit. You'd have to check if this is configurable anywhere in AWS.

I am sending email through mailgun in application(laravel-v10) deployed on EC2. These emails are sent successfully in another application (laarvel-5.6). So what configuration do I need to check on AWS ?

I am sending email in queued job. can it be the issue ?
